# Is there a more elegant syntax for these boolean expressions?

Tags: c++, syntax, boolean

I was just writing an improved linear version of a recursive Fibonacci algorithm, and realized that my boolean expressions look really bad and unreadable. Is there a *cleaner* way to do what I'm trying to do?

```
int fibonacci(int num) {

    if (num <= 1)
        return num;

    // starts looking ugly here

    int a = intExists(num-1);
    int b = intExists(num-2);

    bool aAndB = (a != -1 && b != -1);
    bool justA = (a != -1 && b == -1);
    bool justB = (a == -1 && b != -1);

    int number = 0;

    if (aAndB)
        number = (a + b);
    else if (justA)
        number = (a + fibonacci(num - 2));
    else if (justB)
        number = (fibonacci(num-1) + b);
    else
        number = (fibonacci(num - 1) + fibonacci(num - 2));

    map.push_back(Pair(num, number));

    return number;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us `intExists(int)`?

Comment: I hope this is an exercise on how to use *memoization* techniques... there are far better ways of implementing fibonacci.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas like what? This one uses O(n) space and O(n) time. Let me know how I can improve

Comment: I might be missing something, but can't you just check if the element is in the map, if not, calculate, store and return, else fetch and return?

Comment: @OleksiyDobrodum: `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space in asymptotic complexity terms, also no recursion, no memory allocations (which means much lower constant factors. I am not sure how you got to `O(n)` time as you have a lookup in a `std::map` that involves `O(log n)` --you might be right, I have not analyzed the complexity in detail.

Comment: Since F(x) depends on F(0)..F(x-1), which values are memoized can be trivially deduced from the number of memoized values. If you need F(x) and all you have is Y values, with Y<X, then calculate F(Y) to F(X).

Comment: I'm not using a std::map - I'm using a std::vector<Pair> where Pair is a custom struct that represents a key-value pair

Comment: OK, you probably shouldn't call your vector `map`, it confuses people :-)

Comment: Yeah good idea, I'll change it :) It does represent a map in practice, so I felt like it was a good name for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about:

```
bool aAndB = (a != -1 && b != -1);
```

then I would say, "no."

This code looks perfectly expressive to me.  `aAndB` is initialized at the moment it comes in to being, and the conditions are very clear.  This might look a bit odd when you're first starting out in C++, but before you know it it will be second nature and other constructs will  seem silly.

One thing I would suggest is to make `aAndB` `const` if you don't intend to change it:

```
const bool aAndB = (a != -1 && b != -1);
```

This is even more expressive.

It also might give the compiler an additional opportunity to optimize your code.

Remember -- write code for *humans* to understand.  Not for computers to understand.

Comment: +1 For "write code for *humans* to understand. Not for computers to understand."

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you make `a` and `b` as `bool`s and assign those as `true` if `a == -1` and `false` otherwise.  Then, the expressions will become easier to handle.

Comment: Agree. It's a mess because the booleans are not booleans.

Comment: They do not have to be `int`.  There is no explicit requirement for that.  The OP just wrote his/her code that way and is looking for a better way to express the code.

Answer (score 1):

Could do a switch statement to clean up the if else statements a little. Other than that just add comments

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite it to use conditional branching, like this:

```
int fibonacci(int num) {

    if (num <= 1)
        return num;

    int a = intExists(num-1);
    int b = intExists(num-2);

    const bool isA = (a != -1);   // change in the definition
    const bool isB = (b != -1);   // change in the definition

    int number = 0;

    if (isA && isB)
        number = (a + b);
    else if (isA)   // conditionnal branching
        number = (a + fibonacci(num - 2));
    else if (isB)   // conditionnal branching
        number = (fibonacci(num-1) + b);
    else
        number = (fibonacci(num - 1) + fibonacci(num - 2));

    map.push_back(Pair(num, number));

    return number;
}
```

Comment: How is this better?  Or even different?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `intExists(n)` looks up `map` and if finds `n` in there, returns `fibonacci(n)` else it returns `-1`. Then you could do this:

```
int fibonacci(int num) {

    if (num <= 1)
        return num;

    int a = intExists(num-1);
    int b = intExists(num-2);

    if (a == -1) // if a wasn't found, then compute it
        a = fibonacci(num-1);

    if (b == -1) // if b wasn't found, then compute it
        b = fibonacci(num-2);

    int number = a + b;
    map.push_back(std::make_pair(num, number));

    return number;
}
```

**Bonus:**

Here is another completely different implementation of `fibonnacci()` based on [Binet's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binet_formula#Closed-form_expression):

```
#include <cmath>

int fibonacci(int n) {
    static const double e1 =  1.6180339887498948482045868343656;  // = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2
    static const double e2 = -0.61803398874989484820458683436564; // = (1 - sqrt(5)) / 2
    static const double c =   0.44721359549995793928183473374626; // = 1 / sqrt(5);
    double f = c * (std::pow(e1, n) - std::pow(e2, n));
    return static_cast<int>(f + 0.5);
}

int main() {
    for (int n = 1; n < 15; ++n)
        std::cout << fibonacci(n) << ' ';
}
```

It outputs:

> > 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377

Answer (score 0):

Plain C++ code is clean enough:

```
bool a = intExists(num-1);
bool b = intExists(num-2);

if (a && b) {
  //
} else if (a) {
  //
} else if (b) {
  //
} else {
  //
}
```

Comment: @Kyle_the_hacker: No, they don't. "Exists" is a boolean predicate. Something either exists or it does not. Something does not exist "5" or "blue".

Comment: According to the question, `intExists(int)` gives `-1` in some cases... ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = intExists(num-1);
int b = intExists(num-2);

bool aAndB = (a != -1 && b != -1);
bool justA = (a != -1 && b == -1);
bool justB = (a == -1 && b != -1);
```

Quick look into the approach you took. *Under what circumstances can `justB` be `true`?* (Hint: never)

That should help you simplify your approach, although there are better approaches than *memoization*.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `intExists` to return boolean values, you can do a switch-case statements like that:

```
bool a = intExists(num-1);
bool b = intExists(num-2); 

switch ((a << 1) + b) {
default: // none exists
case 1: // only b exist
case 2: // only a exist
case 3: // both exists
}
```

The rationale is to transform those booleans in a binary number

Answer (score 0):

A slightly drastic rewrite is to let an external function handle the lookup table.
That way you don't need to care about more than one value at a time.

This one uses `map` so I didn't have to write so much in order to test it, but it should be easy enough to adapt:

```
std::map<int, int> table;

int fibonacci(int num);

int value(int num)
{
    int result = table[num];
    if (!result)
    {
        result = fibonacci(num);
        table[num] = result;
    }
    return result;
}

int fibonacci(int num) 
{
    if (num <= 2)
        return 1;
    return value(num - 1) + value(num - 2);
}
```